# Why is this setTimeout callback unable to change a variable to end a while loop?

Tags: javascript

I’ve been playing around with some code, and I’ve discovered that the following does not act as expected:

```
var truth = true;
var x = 0;

setTimeout( ()=> truth = false, 10);

while(truth === true){
  console.log(x+=1)
}
```

My assumption was that the while loop would be ended after the callback in setTimeout changed the “truth” value, but the while loop seems to run infinitely...

Can someone explain why? I’m definitely missing an aspect of Javascript which can explain this behavior!

Thank you!

Comment: Callbacks for timers (and other async callbacks) don't run until your main code has run to completion, which it never does in this case.

Comment: Thank you Mark, that solves it!